# column width adjustment in python docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I am using python docx. I want to adjust column width. It works in my code in portrait mode. but, when I change the page orientation to landscape it does not work for me.

```
document.add_page_break()
new_section = document.add_section(WD_SECTION.ODD_PAGE)
new_section.orientation = WD_ORIENT.LANDSCAPE
new_section.page_width  = Inches(11.7)
new_section.page_height = Inches(8.3)
document.add_heading('Multiple Setter', level=1)
table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=5)
table.allow_autofit = False
table.alignment = WD_TABLE_ALIGNMENT.LEFT
table.style = "Table Grid"
hdr_cells = table.rows[0].cells
hdr_cells[0].width = Cm(4)
hdr_cells[0].text = 'Variable'
hdr_cells[1].width = Cm(5)
hdr_cells[1].text = 'Function Writing'
```

can you please guide me whats wrong?

Comment: Can you link to the docx package you're using?

Comment: I think so: from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
from ast import literal_eval
from docx.enum.style import WD_STYLE_TYPE
from docx.enum.table import WD_TABLE_ALIGNMENT
from docx.enum.section import WD_ORIENT
from docx.enum.section import WD_SECTION
from docx.shared import Inches,Pt
from docx.shared import Cm